# Simplifying a log function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How come:

```
y=c1*e^(c2*t)
```

is simplified to:

```
ln(y)=ln(c1)+c2*t
```

?

What I got is:

```
ln(y) = ln(c1*e^(c2*t))
ln(y) = (c2*t) * ln(c1*e)
ln(y) = (c2*t) * (ln(c1) + ln(e))
ln(y) = (c2*t) * ln(c1)
```

i.e. I have a multiplication sign when it should be addition sign. I don't get how there should be an addition sign. Any explanation is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take care : $\log(a \times b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly used (or perhaps failed to use) the product rule of logarithms. Given positive numbers $a$ and $b,$ we have $$\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln(a)+\ln(b).$$ In particular, $$\ln(c_1e^{c_2t})=\ln(c_1)+\ln(e^{c_2t})=\ln(c_1)+c_2t.$$

Comment: Ohhhhhh! I've been overthinking today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that you need to know not just the arithmetic operations but also the **precedence rules**. $ae^b = a \times ( e^b )$, which is why $\ln(ae^b) = \ln(a) + \ln(e^b)$ when $a > 0$. "$ae^b$" does not mean "$( a \times e )^b$", which is why it is incorrect that $\ln(ae^b) = b \ln(ae)$.